# Create a tag for an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to give a tag for an NSString by creating a category:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringTag;
```

.m:

```
- (NSString *)stringTag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, CFBridgingRetain(kStringTagKey));
}
- (void)setStringTag:(NSString *)stringTag
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, CFBridgingRetain(kStringTagKey), stringTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}
```

However I'm getting these errors:

[image]

Comment: Are you including the runtime .h file?

Comment: @godel9 No, do I have to import it?

Comment: Probably you need to include #import <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Comment: +1 You beat me in both comment and answer as well :D

Comment: @JanakNirmal :-) Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy New Year to you too ! :D

Answer (score 6):

Please add an import statement as

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```